# Navigation bar shrinks when pushed to the new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ios14

I have a detail view controller, it has `tableView` which shows the user info. But when I pushed from another view controller to the detail view controller navigation bar always shrinks, even I force to be the large title and not set it anywhere else. If I scroll down it shows as a large title. Have you encountered such an issue before?

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)

     navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
     navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
 }
```

note: version, iOS 14.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to set appearance.

```
 let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor(named: "menuNavBarTitle") ?? .red]
    navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor(named: "menuNavBarTitle") ?? .red]
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```